# Run function every 3 seconds

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I need to find the position of an object every 3 seconds. This code constantly gets the position of the object. What am I doing Wrong?

```
function checkpoint (){
    last_checkpoint_X = player.transform.position.x;
}
function Update(){
    InvokeRepeating("checkpoint", 10, 3.0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use the Unity3D [`MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html) function. Try this:

```
function Checkpoint () {
  Debug.Log("repeating the Checkpoint function");
}

InvokeRepeating("Checkpoint", 10, 3.0);
```

Let us know if you get that message in your logs every 3 seconds.

Comment: I get the message in the log constantly. After 3 seconds it was in my logs almost 200 times

Comment: @TonyC the problem is somewhere else then. You're using InvokeRepeating correctly, you're probably just calling it 200 times.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was my own dumb fault. I had InvokeRepeating in my Update function

Answer (score 0):

Use window.setTimeout API. For more details search on google

Comment: SetTimeout isn't in unity. From what I found InvokeRepeating is supposed to be the equivalent in unity but it's not working.

Comment: Mea culpa thought it was javascript